# Identity Server 4 and external provider returning plain HTML if unauthenticated

Tags: c#, openid-connect, identityserver4

We have a machine running IdentityServer4 which itself is used as a federated gateway to Office 365.

I'm trying to figure out how to circumvent this scenario: we create an MVC-app that has the following owin-startup class:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                SlidingExpiration = false
            });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = "https://localhost:5000/",
            ClientId = "dev",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:54509/",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile account",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                    {
                        "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                    };

                    var claims_to_keep =
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                        .Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                    claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                        "name", "role");
                    ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                    );
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {

                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

            }
        });

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

So far so good: upon first visiting the user is redirected to the Identity Server, signing in and getting back but when they lose their token or become unauthenticated and try to access a controller decorated with [Authorize] the plain HTML of the sign-on site is returned to that controller.

Are we using the wrong flow for this back channel, server-to-server communication? Or is there a way to intercept this so that they can be redirected immediately before the controller freaks out over getting HTML instead of JSON.